# Find the vertices of the polygon given by $|f_1(x,y)|+...+|f_n(x,y)| \le C$

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

Given functions $f_1(x,y),...,f_n(x,y)$, we know that the locus of points $(x,y)$ satisfying $|f_1(x,y)|+...+|f_n(x,y)| \le C$ for some real constants $C$ is the interior of a polygon. How do I find the vertices of the polygon in general?

I ask this because I was trying to find the area of the region described by

$|x|+|x+y|+|x-2y|\le 10$

and I know this is a polygon, probably symmetric, so it suffices to find the vertices and then connect the dots to find the polygon, and the rest is simple. The problem is how would I find the vertices in a non-tedious way (without plotting the $2^3=8$ separate inequalities).

Comment: Why so little views?